# XMLGregorianCalendar date with timestamp into Time stamp with timezone column in databse

Tags: java, oracle, calendar, timezone, gregorian-calendar

how to save XMLGrgorianCalendar date with timestamp into database column which is of type "Time stamp with timezone"

Comment: Are you using postgres as database?

Comment: Oracle is my database